# apt-get update error using automatic proxy configuration

Tags: apt, updates, security, vmware

I am using Ubuntu 10.4.04 LTS with in VMware5. 
I used automatic proxy configuration and I'm able to use internet from firefox.
When I wanted to update `apt-get update`, I am getting following errors.
The following link gives some solution, but I don't have any port number as I'm using automatic proxy
https://answers.launchpad.net/uck/+question/108860.

Error:

```
Ign http security.ubuntu.com lucid-security multiverse Packages              
Ign http security.ubuntu.com lucid-security multiverse Sources               
Ign http security.ubuntu.com lucid-security main Packages                                  
Err http security.ubuntu.com lucid-security main Packages                    
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Packages              
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Sources                     
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Sources               
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Err http security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Packages
  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
W: Failed to fetch http security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US.bz2  Something wicked happened resolving 'security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get` does not use the global proxy settings. Try adding the proxy settings to `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<your-proxy-url>";
```

Or just run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo su
echo 'Acquire::http::proxy "http://<your-proxy-url>";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I added this setting to apt.conf but I am getting "E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf:2: Extra junk after value" error. I spent some time on internet to find out but I couldn't, so I came back again. Thank you for the reply. Uma

Comment: Maybe you got my answer wrong. I updated it to make it more clear that the code example was meant to be run in terminal.

Comment: thank you! Now its connecting to proxy but I am getting same errors "W: Failed to fetch http security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid-security/multiverse/source/Sources.gz  404  Not Found
Err http security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found" Actually I want to install "xinetd"

Comment: That's strange. Maybe you have to specify a port number, like `http://<some-url>:<port-number>/`? Although a wrong port should lead to different errors.

Answer (score 0):

It works now!

For some reason my proxy url is failing to connect but I opened `proxy.pac` and added **ALL** proxy urls in `apt.conf`.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)